# Append columns to a table by selecting columns from another table

Tags: sql

```
Alter Table table2 add ( select column1, column2, column3, column4 from table1 );
```

I need to append columns in an existing table, by selecting the columns of another table.

I get Error! Looking forward for a possible solution

Comment: What are you trying to do? Dynamically add columns to a table based on values in another table? Could you give an example of your data and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Am just trying to append 4 columns with values from another table to my table. There are no conditions..

Comment: Sorry this is still not clear. Can you please give an example of your data and the result?

Comment: So lets take this in two steps: 1. Your existing table has has some number of columns and you need to add four additional columns to the table correct? 2. You have existing data from a different table that needs to be inserted into the table with the four new columns. Does that data need to be inserted as brand new rows where just the four new columns are populated with data? Or do you have specific rows existing in the first table for which you need to insert the data for the new columns?

Answer (score 0):

First, to add four new columns to the table use the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2
            ADD  column1 <datatype> <allow null>,
                 column2 <datatype> <allow null>,
                 column3 <datatype> <allow null>,
                 column4 <datatype> <allow null>
```

Where `<datatype>` is the type of data you'll be adding to the column and `<allow null>` is `NULL` if you want to allow null values is the column and `NOT NULL` if you do not want to allow null values in the column.

For example to add four columns of type nchar with a size of 10 that allow null values you would do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2
            ADD  column1 [nchar](10) NULL,
                 column2 [nchar](10) NULL,
                 column3 [nchar](10) NULL,
                 column4 [nchar](10) NULL
```

Next, to insert your data from table1 into this table as brand new record you would use the following sql:

```
insert into     table2 (column1, column2, column3, column4)
                select column1, column2, column3, column4
                from table1
```

Note: if any of the original columns in your table are set to `NOT NULL` and do not have have a default value this will fail and you will have to set values for those columns as well. You would do that by using a command similar to where you set a specific value for the column not allowing NULL values:

```
insert into     table2 ( existingColumn, column1, column2, column3, column4)
                select 'value to insert', column1, column2, column3, column4
                from table1
```